# Having issues using a library when debugging in Visual Studio 2022 but not when running from command line

Tags: c#, rfid

I have some demo codelets that come with a RFID reader from Jadak. The API is Mercury API. The codelets are meant to demonstrate various aspects of the API. They target .NET4. It seems I can build the project and go to the bin>Debug folder and run the codelet in a doc command prompt. If I run the project in debug mode in VS 2022 I get to a line to connect to the reader and about a 10 second delay. At that point I get the following:

[image]

It seems to be throwing an exception when debugging but not when running the compiled version directly. Not sure where to go with this.

Comment: Check the project bin folder and see if both the Debug and Release executables were updated on same date.  Usually this happens when you build only one of the two executables.

Comment: There are no release executables built yet. The exe that I am running from command line successfully is in the debug folder. I also deleted the debug folder and tried running in debug in VS and then running the exe from command line. Same result. Command line runs, VS debug does not.

Comment: Great.  Answer is simple.  When you run inside VS you do not have Admin Privilege.  So start VS by right click  shortcut an select Run As Admin.   The exe will automatically run as admin but not inside VS.

Comment: @jdweng - I just tried running VS as admin. That did not help. I confirmed deleted the contents of bin/debug and rebuilt. Did not help.

Comment: Look at the original location of file in the LLRP picture.  It is in the Program Files folder which users do not have permission to write.  You are probably not an Admin which is the reason for your error.

Comment: When I run in debug mode from visual studio (running as admin or no) it fails. When I run the exe that visual studio created in bin/debug when I just cpmpiled then it runs fine. Bin/debug is not on programs folder.

Comment: The pdb is debug info which means you are running from debug and not release.  Also is means the pdb is does not exist or you do not have permission to read.  Make sure you build the LLRP project in debug mode and not release mode.  Remember that when you are running inside VS you do not have ADMIN unless you start VS with shortcut and select Run As Admin.